# How to build a reliable bank transfer?

Tags: database-theory, software-engineering, reliability

I recently came across a problem where I was charged $50 by a merchant with my bank card but there was a communication error, so the money was taken from my account but never arrived in the merchants account.  I have contacted both banks and neither know what happened to the money.

How could one would construct software to avoid this problem?

Comment: This is essentially, "How do you design reliable software?", which is far too broad.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems)

Comment: ACID -- that that could happen speaks volumes about the quality of the involved IT. Blerg.